# Call C function in C++ class implementation

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, gumbo

I have to use https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser library that is written in C.

I have a `HtmlParser` class which is defined in `HtmlParser.h` and I implement it's methods in `HtmlParser.cpp`

I include `gumbo.h` in `HtmlParser.h` and call it's functions in implemented by me `getLinks(...)` function that is in `HtmlParser.cpp`

When I try to compile it I get **undefined reference to 'gumbo_parse'**
How can I fix it?

My makefile is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(WebCrawler)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp HtmlParser.cpp HtmlParser.h)
add_executable(WebCrawler ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: How do you compile? Post your makefile or similar.

Comment: @harald
I've added a makefile

Comment: C or C++? Might be important.

Comment: @SergeyA

I'm writing in C++ and using a C library

Comment: Just what I guessed. Check if your include file has a proper extern "C" around function definitions.

Comment: @SergeyA
Yes, it has.

`#ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" {` at the beggining of gumbo.h

Comment: Wait. I do not see any external libs to be added to your executable in CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @SergeyA So, how can I add It? I'm using CLion and I thought that It cares about these things.

Comment: Not sure about CLion. In vanilla CMake you'd use `target_link_libraries` to add libraries to the executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `undefined reference` is an error at link time. It means the symbol (function) that you're using and for which the definition was found when compiling the compilation unit cannot be resolved at link time to link against.

If you build in only one command, you probably just need to add a `-lgumbo` to your command line, eventually with `-L<path to directory containing libgumbo.so>` if it's not in the default lib path. Typically:

```
g++ main.cc -lgumbo
```

or if gumbo lib and headers are in gumbo subdirectories:

```
g++ main.cc -I/usr/local/include/gumbo/ -L/usr/local/lib/gumbo/ -lgumbo
```

If you build in multiple command lines (first building objects, then linking them, then you need to add the `-l` (and eventually `-L`) options to the link command:

```
g++ main.cc -o main.o # This is the objects building command
g++ main.o -l gumbo   # This is the linking command
```

**Edit:** With `cmake` (that I now see you're using), you must tell that you're using gumbo library. This should be done using [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3afind_library):

```
find_library(gumbo)
```

If not supported you may need to use [`link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3Alink_directories) to specify where to find it. Then use [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) to specify to link with this library for your target.

Comment: OP is using CMake, your answer doesn't cover it.

Comment: Please explain the downvote ... If it's because of the cmake, I started writing the answer before the info about it was added and edited after to refine my answer !

Comment: Well, now that you added this, the downvote is gone :)

Comment: Thanks :-) I just wanted to be sure this was the reason